# What are Forward Slashes in XSLT for?

Tags: xslt, formatting, xsl-fo

I'm fairly new to XSLT and was wondering what the forward slashes are for.

For example:

> xsl:apply-templates select="/foo/bar"

What should the template name of the above apply-template be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `select` attribute of `apply-templates` is an *XPath expression* which selects nodes from your input XML - in this case all the `bar` elements under the `foo` element which is the top-level element in the input document.  The full details of XPath syntax can be found in the XPath specifications - [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-path-expressions) if you're using the current XSLT version 2.0 and [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths) if you're stuck with the old XSLT version 1.0.

The template that will be applied to each of those nodes will be chosen by looking at their `match` patterns, and (roughly speaking) the "most specific" template that could apply to each node will be the one chosen.  So if the only possible match is

```
<xsl:template match="bar">
```

then that will be chosen for all of them, but if there was also an

```
<xsl:template match="bar[1]">
```

then this would be used for the first `bar` and the less-specific template would be used for the others.  The principle of separating the selection of which nodes to process from the decision on exactly *how* to process each one is something that takes a bit of getting used to when you first start out with XSLT but once you understand it it makes the language very powerful.

I would recommend you find a good XSLT tutorial online and work through that to gain a better understanding of the concepts.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian.  That clarified it!